# Cplex Random Number Generator With Certain Interval

Tags: cplex

I'm using IBM CPLEX Optimization Studio and I want to write a function that generates a random value of a distance between two customers and saves it in a tuple including the indices of the customers. The values should be between 2 and 5.

```
execute Pupulate_TupleDistance_RandNo{
var i,j
for (var i in customers) {
for (var j in customers) {
if (i != j) {TravelMatrix.add(i, j, Opl.maxl(2,Opl.rand(5)))} 
}}
};
```

This is what my function looks like so far but it gives me the maximum value in the chosen interval. How do I have to change it to give me the random value between 2 and 5?

Answer (score 0):

This [technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21595936) says:

> rand(m)- Returns a pseudo random integer modulo m (thus the number
>   will be between 0 and m-1, both inclusive).

To get values between 2 and 5 inclusive, I think you can you simply replace:

```
Opl.maxl(2,Opl.rand(5)))
```

with:

```
2 + Opl.rand(4)
```